# What is the joint distribution of X,Y?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The question reads as follows. A person has a pencil case containing 10 pencils: 3 blue, 3 yellow, 3 red and 1 orange pencil. The person takes pencils out of the case one by one and without replacement until they have taken out the orange pencil.

Define: X - The number of red pencils taken out of the case.
Y - The number of different coloured pencils taken out of the case.
Z - The total number of pencils taken out of the case.
The question asks us to find the joint distribution of X,Y.

I tried finding the CDF using brute force but after getting to $P(X=0,Y=3)$ I came across a problem of making calculation errors and excessive numbers. Is there any distribution I can use to bypass this method or any other method or is this the only way to go about it? All help is appreciated!